# alertdialog listview with custom adapter shows nothing

Tags: android, listview, android-alertdialog

I'm using a listview in an alertdialog, but when the dialog shows, its doesn't display anything. The object is not empty as I'm filling it and adding it to the array list before the alertdialog. Heres the code for my xml and classes:

Where I'm setting the adapter:

```
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
            builder.setTitle("Select a match");
            //insert array to constructor
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater(savedInstanceState);
            View dialogLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialoglist, null);
            matchAdapter testAdapter = new matchAdapter(getContext(), userInfos);
            ListView listView = (ListView) dialogLayout.findViewById(R.id.dialogListView);
            listView.setAdapter(testAdapter);
            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    //do something
                }
            });
            builder.setView(dialogLayout);

            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
```

custom adapter:

```
class matchAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<userInfo> {

public matchAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<userInfo> test) {
    super(context, R.layout.match_result, test);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());

    View customRow = inflater.inflate(R.layout.match_result, parent, false);
    userInfo singleItemTest = getItem(position);

    /*
    TODO: get references to layout elements
     */

    TextView username = (TextView) customRow.findViewById(R.id.matchUsername);
    TextView sex = (TextView) customRow.findViewById(R.id.matchSex);
    TextView age = (TextView) customRow.findViewById(R.id.matchAge);
    Button sendRequest = (Button) customRow.findViewById(R.id.matchSendRequest);

    username.setText(singleItemTest.getUserName());

    return customRow;
}}
```

row.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/match_result"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:padding="16dp"
android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
android:gravity="left">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/matchUsername"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Username"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/matchSex"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Sex"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/matchAge"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Age"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>


<Button
    android:id="@+id/matchSendRequest"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Send Request"
    android:minHeight="5dp"
    android:minWidth="0dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"/>
```

dialoglist.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/dialogListView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

</ListView>
```

Comment: Use fragment as dialog

Comment: Could you show what you mean, in code?

Comment: http://javatechig.com/android/android-dialog-fragment-example  Use it as example

Comment: There's no need to delete and repost your question. Simply editing your original post will bump it to the top of the active queue.

Comment: You're apparently doing this in a `Fragment`. What is `savedInstanceState`, and how are you getting a `LayoutInflater` from it? The rest of your code is fine, but that part is suspicious.

Comment: Yes I am doing this in a fragment. savedInstancestate is passed in to onViewCreated()

Comment: The dialog still doesn't display anything when it shows.

Comment: Are you sure `userInfos` isn't empty when you create the `Adapter`? Have you checked its `size()` at that point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mike. M was correct in his comment. The arraylist was indeed empty. However I've fixed it now. Dumb oversight on my for loop.

Answer (score 0):

In your Adapter add a object `ArrayList<userInfo> infos`

Now in Constractor use this

```
public matchAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<userInfo> test) {
    super(context, R.layout.match_result, test);
    infos=test;

}
```

Now `getView` callback will like this:

```
userInfo singleItemTest = infos.get(position);
```

I think this will solve your problem :)

Comment: That's basically the same thing the `ArrayAdapter` is already doing by default.

Comment: In the array adapter, override and the getCount() method and return infos.size()

Comment: @KanchanChowdhury Again, that's the same thing the `ArrayAdapter` is already doing by default

Comment: @KanchanChowdhury Sure thing. The OP's code is calling the `super` constructor with the `List`, so the `ArrayAdapter` class is handling these things. If they hadn't passed it the `List`, then these things would need to be handled in the subclass.